# bootbox is stopping dropdown-menu to work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, bootbox

I have asp.net core MVC using bootbox.
I noticed that my dropdown-menu is not working, I tried everything like removing the js files and CSS files and re add them again but with no luck until I removed bootbox.js and bom! and the dropdown menu works fine.

here is my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar-sa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - POS3</title>

    <script src="~/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />





    @*<script src="~/js/popper.min.js"></script>*@


</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">POS<sup>3</sup></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />

                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="SelectedItems" asp-action="POSMain">POSMain</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <il class="dropdown-item">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Create">Add New Product</a>
                            </il>
                        </ul>                
                      
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>


                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
</div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container" >
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2019 - POS3 - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("Menu", required: false)
    @RenderSection("ProductScript", false)
</body>
</html>
```

I think there is something in bootbox.js that is just stopping the dropdown to work as usual.

Comment: You have four different references to jQuery. I'd start there. You also need to load bootbox.js AFTER bootstrap.js, which you've loaded twice. Bootbox is not the issue, here.

Comment: @TiesonT. I removed the other JQuery references and but bootbox after bootstrap.js but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: "it didn't work" doesn't really help - if you made changes to how you're setting up your page, then please update your question to reflect that (the edit button is beneath the tags, in the lower left of your question).

Comment: Given that the main reason I basically took over maintenance of Bootbox was because I was/am using all of the technologies you've tagged this with, I *know* it works, so there's something wrong with how you're building your page. Your current code (as shown) has a lot of issues that need to be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything else in your project is built correctly, your layout has a bunch of issues that need to be fixed:

1. You've included jQuery quite a few times. Remove all but one.
2. You've loaded two different versions of bootstrap.js, and out of order.
3. You added bootbox.js as the first script, in the `<head>`. [As we note
   in our docs](http://bootboxjs.com/getting-started.html#bb-script-order),
   Bootbox needs to be loaded AFTER Bootstrap (since it's a Bootstrap extension).

So, removing the redundancies and fixing the script order, here's what you're left with (I spaced the scripts out at the end, so that you can see what's loaded):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar-sa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - POS3</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">POS<sup>3</sup></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />

                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="SelectedItems" asp-action="POSMain">POSMain</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <il class="dropdown-item">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Create">Add New Product</a>
                            </il>
                        </ul>                

                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>


                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container" >
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2019 - POS3 - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>

    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("Menu", required: false)
    @RenderSection("ProductScript", false)
</body>
</html>
```